# Function for factorial in Python

Tags: python

How do I go about computing a factorial of an integer in Python?

Answer (score 242):

The easiest way is to use [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.factorial) (available in Python 2.6 and above):

```
import math
math.factorial(1000)
```

If you want/have to write it yourself, you can use an iterative approach:

```
def factorial(n):
    fact = 1
    for num in range(2, n + 1):
        fact *= num
    return fact
```

or a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) approach:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Note that the [factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is only defined for positive integers, so you should also check that `n >= 0` and that [`isinstance(n, int)`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance). If it's not, raise a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) or a [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) respectively. `math.factorial` will take care of this for you.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you can use `factorial` within the `factorial` function. How can you use the same function within the function you're currently defining? I'm new to Python so I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @J82: The concept used here is called recursion ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) ) - a function calling itself is perfectly fine and often useful.

Comment: The recursive function will raise a [`RecursionError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError) for any number larger than 998 (try `factorial(999)`) unless you [increase Python's recursion limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323008/3064538)

Comment: Raising CPython's recursion limit is dangerous -- you can kill the interpreter. Just [don't use recursion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988828/why-is-python-recursion-so-expensive-and-what-can-we-do-about-it) if it can be helped (it usually can, as this example illustrates).

Comment: factorial(999) ≈ 4.02 × 10^2564, so it's unlikely you would want to compute such a large number anyway.

Answer (score 120):

On Python 2.6 and up, try:

```
import math
math.factorial(n)
```

Comment: [Starting with Python 3.9](https://bugs.python.org/issue37315), passing a `float` to this function will raise a `DeprecationWarning`. If you want to do that, you need to convert `n` to an `int` explicitly: `math.factorial(int(n))`, which will discard anything after the decimal, so you might want to check that [`n.is_integer()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number)

Answer (score 24):

### Existing solution

The shortest and probably the fastest solution is:

```
from math import factorial
print factorial(1000)
```

### Building your own

You can also build your own solution. Generally you have two approaches. The one that suits me best is:

```
from itertools import imap
def factorial(x):
    return reduce(long.__mul__, imap(long, xrange(1, x + 1)))

print factorial(1000)
```

(it works also for bigger numbers, when the result becomes `long`)

The second way of achieving the same is:

```
def factorial(x):
    result = 1
    for i in xrange(2, x + 1):
        result *= i
    return result

print factorial(1000)
```

Comment: `operator.mul` could be used instead of `long.__mul__` and it would work in both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul).

Answer (score 8):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Comment: `factorial(999)` (and above) will raise a `RuntimeError` unless you [increase Python's recursion limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323008/3064538)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Python 2.5 or older, try

```
from operator import mul

def factorial(n):
    return reduce(mul, range(1, n+1))
```

For newer versions of Python, there is factorial in the *math* module as given in other answers here.

Comment: This is a Python 2-only answer, `reduce` was removed from Python 3.

Comment: @Boris, in Python3 you just need to add `from functools import reduce`

Comment: It was removed for a reason, you shouldn't use it https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Answer (score 7):

#### For performance reasons, please do not use recursion. It would be disastrous.

```
def fact(n, total=1):
    while True:
        if n == 1:
            return total
        n, total = n - 1, total * n
```

#### Check running results

```
cProfile.run('fact(126000)')
```

---

```
4 function calls in 5.164 seconds
```

Using the stack is convenient (like recursive call), but it comes at a cost: storing detailed information can take up a lot of memory.

If the stack is high, it means that the computer stores a lot of information about function calls.

The method only takes up constant memory (like iteration).

#### Or using a 'for' loop

```
def fact(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

#### Check running results

```
cProfile.run('fact(126000)')
```

---

```
4 function calls in 4.708 seconds
```

---

#### Or using the built-in function math

```
def fact(n):
    return math.factorial(n)
```

#### Check running results

```
cProfile.run('fact(126000)')
```

---

```
5 function calls in 0.272 seconds
```

Comment: I think this while loop looks a little bit cleaner 
<!-- language: python -->
def fact(n):
    ret = 1
    while n > 1:
        n, ret = n - 1, ret * n
    return ret

Comment: Looks great, shouting (large font) that recursion is disastrous, but can you back this up? Yes, you need a lot of stack, but only for a very short time. And yesterday's "a lot" is today's "just a little", especially in computing. We write high level code in order to not waste our time, and recursion helps with that. You don't need low level code a lot for performance reasons, today

Comment: It also depends on the context you're using the factorial in -- recursive functions have the benefit of being cache-able, this can be particularly helpful with factorials

Answer (score 6):

```
def fact(n):
    f = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        f *= i
    return f
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to use `np.prod` shown below:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
         return np.prod(np.arange(1,n+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-recursive solution, no imports:

```
def factorial(x):
    return eval(' * '.join(map(str, range(1, x + 1))))
```

Comment: It would be interesting to compare this to some of the other methods presented here.  My guess is it's off-the-charts inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it in one line recursively if you like it. It is just a matter of personal choice. Here we are using inline `if else` in Python, which is similar to the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in Java:

```java
Expression1 ? Expression2 : Expression3
```

- #### One line `function call` approach:

  ```
  def factorial(n): return 1 if n == 0 else n * factorial(n-1)
  ```
- #### One line `lambda` function approach:

  (although it is not recommended to assign lambda functions directly to a name, as it is considered a bad practice and may bring inconsistency to your code. It's always good to know. See *[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)*.)

  ```
  factorial = lambda n: 1 if n == 0 else n * factorial(n-1)
  ```