# How can I sum up the different values within this while loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

This seems so simple yet I am having a hard time getting it to work. I was trying to create a new variable inside the "while loop" to collect the values of x at each loop, like

```
k2 += x
```

but it does not work. So how could I sum up the different values within this while loop? Thank you much.

```
# pi approximation by using Ramanujan Formula

import math

def estimate_pi(k):

    x = (2 * math.sqrt(2)/9801 * math.factorial(4*k) *(1103 + 26390*k))/(math.factorial(k**4)*396**(4*k))
    while x >= 1e-15:
        k += 1
        print '{:>5.15f} {:>5} {:>1}'.format(x, 'for k =', k)
        return estimate_pi(k)

estimate_pi(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned factorial, I would suggest you to take a look at the following:

[factorial using while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187031/2072811)

[factorial using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136463/2072811)

In general, the function would either have a while-loop, or the function would call itself (recursion), but not both.

Your while-loop is simply a if-statement, it will not re-enter the loop because of the `return` statement. You're probably looking for something like this:

```
def estimate_pi(k):
    x = ...
    if x >= ...:
        print ...
        return x + estimate_pi(k+1)
    return 0
```

Comment: You said the function would not enter the while-loop once more because of the `return` statement. How come it does it in Ashwini's code?

Comment: Ashwini's code doesn't re-enter the while-loop either.

Note that your while-loop condition check for the value 'x'. But 'x' never change within the loop. So if your while-loop would re-enter, your code would stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def estimate_pi(k, k2=0):
    ...
    while x >= 1e-15:
        k2 += x
        ...
        return estimate_pi(k, k2)
```

Comment: Thanks. But why is it that this function requires an input for k2 while something like this factorial function does not:
    def factorial(n):
        while n != 0:
            recurse = factorial(n-1)
            result = n * recurse
            return result
        else:
            return 1

Comment: @Quester To remember the previous value of `k2` during recursive calls, we need to pass its value.

Comment: Correct, but isn't it that in the case of the factorial function I posted (which uses a while loop) using the same argument, we would need to remember the value of the variable "result = n*recurse" every-time we go through the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make k2 global but that might be just a bad idea for other reasons, it will work though

```
global k2
def estimate_pi(k):
  global k2
  while x >= 1e-15:
    k2+=x
    ...
```