# Calculating factorials with Python

Tags: python

EDIT: I know I can import factorials but I'm doing this as an exercise

Trying to get the factor of a given number with a function in Python.

For example:
factorial(4) = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24

```
def factorial(x):
    n = x
    while n >= 0:
        x = n * (n - 1)
        n -= 1
    return x
```

Comment: `from math import factorial` done

Comment: Haha I should have known that was going to be said. I meant to say I'm trying to make my own math functions just as exercises.

Comment: Factorial is a good candidate for recursion. Have you tried that?

Comment: `factorial = lambda n:n*factorial(n-1) if n > 1 else 1`

Comment: `def f(x): return x * f(x-1) if x > 1 else 1`

Comment: `factorial = lambda n:reduce(operator.mul,range(n,0,-1))`

Comment: Thanks guys for all of your suggestions!

Comment: If it's an exercise, why come to SO? Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: of coarse its just an excersize ... factorial is not something you would ever actually write for anything ... and almost never use for that matter

Comment: @threed Yes I thought so too but honestly I got so stumped that I wanted to see the right answer. I'm very new to Python so I'm just doing these exercises to try and expand my skills

Comment: Well, good luck, and good choice; Python is my favorite language!

Comment: @threed I've only used it for a day and I already want to toss PHP aside!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this: to make your code work

```
def factorial(x):
    n = 1   # this will store the factorial value
    while x > 0:
        n = n*x
        x -= 1
    return n
```

you got many advice on comments follow it

Comment: Thank you for using my existing code to make this, makes it much easier to understand. I appreciate everyone else in the comments that put in their answer, very helpful in seeing other ways of doing it.

Comment: nice to see u @JoranBeasley

Answer (score 1):

A good way of approaching this would be using recursion where a function calls itself. See [Function for Factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python)

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

---

But in your case your return statement actually breaks out of the while loop. So if you pass in 5 you get 20 back which is obviously not 5! (5 factorial).

Instead, try this:

```
def factorial(x):
   n = 1
   while x > 1:
       n *= x
       x -= 1
   return n

print (factorial(5))
```

But do have a go at the recursive approach.

If you really want to cheat try:

```
import math
math.factorial(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I present an even shorter code for recursive factorial calculation. Not sure if it is faster or slower than other approaches:

```
def fac(n):
    return 1 if n==1 else n*fac(n-1)

fac(10)
3628800
```

Comment: Should be `if n==0` for including the computation of 0 factorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n):
    total = 1
    for num in range(2,n+1):
        total *= num
    return total
```

Comment: better using for loop than while loop

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
n = 10
print(str(n) + "! = ", end = '')
def factorial(n):
    '''
    print factorial number in human way
    '''
    if n < 0:
        return 'factorial() not defined for negative values'
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        print('', n, ' =', end = ' ')
        return 1
    else:
        print('', n, '*', end = '')
        return n * factorial(n - 1)

print(factorial(n))
```

output:

10! =  10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1  = 3628800

Comment: Your solution currently does not work for `n = 0`.

Comment: @AlexK, fixed code for `n = 0`.