# Recursion limit gives error in factorial function

Tags: python, recursion

```
import sys

num = long(raw_input("Enter the number for the factorial -> "))
sys.setrecursionlimit(num + 1)


def fact(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (n * fact(n - 1))


print fact(long(num))
```

Above is the code I used for finding factorial and since the maximum recursion limit depth is '997', I tried to change that using :-

> import sys 
>   sys.setrecursionlimit()

But it still gives error. What else can I do ?

Comment: The recursion limit is not an exact science; there is more to the stack than just the Python function being executed. You would need to add an overhead.

Comment: Use an [iterative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

num = long(raw_input("Enter the number for the factorial -> "))
sys.setrecursionlimit(num + 1)


def fact(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (n * fact(n - 1))


print
print "Factorial is -> ", fact(int(num))
```

> This works perfectly and we can increase the limit  > 997

Comment: Sorry, you can only mark *one* of the answers as accepted, not both. It's fine if you feel your own post is the one that should have the accept mark, the choice is yours and yours alone.

Answer (score 3):

The calling frame also counts. For `fact(10)`, you need **11** frames. Passing in a `long` integer causes some additional work further down the line, requiring another frame. Add two to the count:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(num + 2)
```

Add more if you have other frames calling the code calling the `fact()` function. Note that there really is no point in calling `long()` on the input first; Python will produce a `long` object if needed automatically.

That said, I'd not muck with the recursion limit. Set it to a high value *once*, perhaps, but don't keep adjusting it.

A better idea is to *not use recursion*:

```
def fact(n):
    num = 1
    while n > 1:
        num *= n
        n -= 1
    return num
```

or better still, don't re-invent the wheel and use [`math.factorial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial) instead. From Python 3.2 onwards, the Python implementation uses a [binary split factorial algorithm](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/binarysplitfact.html) (plus a table for the first 21 or so results).

Comment: To run the code in the example, you need one more frame for `long` (that's where the mystery frame was coming from).

Comment: @JaredGoguen: No, because `long()` has already returned before `fact()` is invoked.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: ah, but that does muck with the stack elsewhere as values are converted. I can reproduce with `long100 = 100L` then `sys.setrecursionlimit(101)` and `fact(long100)`.