# How to find out factorial number through user input in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find out the factorial number through user input, i have tried this way but answer show nothing here is my code:

[image]

Image show the Factorial code where i am facing the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function for Factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python)

Comment: U need to cast your input into an int first.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to implement recursion in a loop where the input is always given by the user. This causes your recursive setup to act differently than expected. Instead you can implement it as follows

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
n = int(input("enter the number"))# for python3.x
print(factorial(n))
```

Now that `n = input("enter the number")` is outside the recursive loop it is only called once and n is not externally updated during the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Please Remove Line 2 on code:

```
def factorial(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
n = int(input("enter the number"))#python 3.x
print(factorial(n))
```

Comment: thank you so much but can you explain me why it was wrong ? kindly

Comment: You were calling the function `factorial(n)`, but you haven't define `n` outside the function. that's why you getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use math library in python.

```
import math

def factorial():
    n= int(input("enter a number"))
    print("Factorial of number ", math.factorial(n))

factorial()
```

Or

```
def factorial():
    n = int(input("enter a number:"))
    factorial = 1
    if n == 0:
        print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
    else:
       for i in range(1,n + 1):
           factorial = factorial*i
       print("The factorial of number:",factorial)
```

You can also add a check for number below 0 and use elif .
Or,

```
def factorial(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)  
n = int(input("enter the number"))  
print(factorial(n))
```

**Inputs by default is String, You need to convert it to int**

Comment: Use python libraries which are available and save lot of development time .

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
print(math.factorial(int(input("enter the number"))))
```

Comment: While this is a nice two-liner, it's not very Pythonic. Also you may want to *explain* why your solution is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By for:

```
num=int(input("Enter The Number to show it factorial:"))
fact=1
for x in range(1,num+1):
     fact*=x
print("the factorial of this number is({})".format(fact))
```

By while:

```
n=int(input("Enter The Number:"))
x=1
fact=1
while(x<=n):
     fact*=x
     x+=1
     print(fact)
```