# Why can't I multiply by a specific part of range?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python, and I am having trouble making a factorial program.

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

for i in range(num-(num-1), num+1):
    print(num*(i[1]))
```

Why can't I multiply by the first part of a range sequence? I would also like to know how to make it so that it automatically multiplies by the next part of i, (i[2]), automatically without having to manually write it down.

Comment: First, `num-(num-1)` is always `1`, so your sequence is `range(1, num+1)`. Secondly, `i` is an integer and doesn't support indexing. You also seem to be missing a right parenthesis, but that might just be a copy-paste error. I'm unsure what you mean by your question though.

Comment: In your code, which variable are you expecting to be a range. Are you trying to multiply a range of numbers? Then range(start, stop) will be the approach while multiplying the value from range with num. note that range goes from start to stop-1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function for Factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python)

Comment: I am trying to multiply num by the first number in a range sequence

Comment: `result = 1; for i in range(2, num+1): result = result * i; print(result)` gives you your factorial I believe.

Comment: It works, but can you explain how it works?