# Why with an input of 4 the product would be 24?

Tags: python

```
product = 1
end_value = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(1, end_value+1)        
    product = product * I
    i += 1
print("The product is ", product)
```

Can someone explain how with an input of 4 the product is 24?

Comment: what is `I`? `I` is different to  `i`

Comment: why `i += 1` in a loop of `for i in range(...)`?

Comment: assuming your wrote `product = product * i` (lowercase `i`), then `24 == 4 * 1*2*3`, just as the code says.

Comment: perhaps search for "factorial in Python". See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136463/758174).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is "Why with an input of 4 the product would be 24?"

Because 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24

However, that's not what your code is doing. You have an unknown variable `I` (typo?) and you are incrementing `i` again inside your for-loop.

Change `I` back to `i` and remove `i += 1`

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in your code. For loops are used for iterating over data structures, so there is no need to increment i, like `i += 1`, inside a for loop.

```
product = 1
end_value = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(1, end_value+1):
    product = product * i
print("The product is ", product)
```

#### When end_value = 4

**First Iteration:**

```
product = 1
i = 1
product = product * i ===> (product = 1*1)
```

*now value of product is 1. This is passed onto next iteration.*

**Second Iteration:**

```
product = 1
i = 2
product = product * i ===> (product = 1*2)
```

*now value of product is 2. This is passed onto next iteration.*

**Third Iteration:**

```
product = 2
i = 3
product = product * i ===> (product = 2*3)
```

*now value of product is 6. This is passed onto next iteration.*

**Fourth Iteration:**

```
product = 6
i = 4
product = product * i ===> (product = 6*4)
```

*now value of product is 24. After the fourth iteration, the for loop stops and the value of product is printed as 24.*

**Output**

```
Enter a number: 4
The product is 24
```