# For loop / While proble

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to solve this problem:

"For any number code the next series:"

n = any number (1 for this case)

1,2,6,24,120,720...

This series is:

**1**x1 = **1**

**1**x2 = **2**

**2**x3 = **6**

**6**x4 = **24**

**24**x5 = **120**

And so on....

I don't know how keep the first value (maybe a cont=0) and how use the for loop or the while loop.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function for factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python)

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following code can help you
maybe you can try to make this question simpler
This is my solotion, and it works

```
start=1
stop=10 # you can set your own
for a in range(1,stop+1):
    print("{}*{}=".format(start,a),end='')
    start=start*a
    print(start)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that @Samwise already answer it when I post my own, his solution is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You're keeping track of two different numbers here -- there's the number that's produced in the series (`n`) and the number that you're multiplying each successive `n` by (let's call that `k`).  So the natural thing is to have a loop that iterates over the values in `k` and multiplies each one by `n` to get the next value of `n`:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> for k in range(1, 6):
...     print(f"{n}x{k} = ", end="")
...     n *= k
...     print(n)
...
1x1 = 1
1x2 = 2
2x3 = 6
6x4 = 24
24x5 = 120
```